# Only one eth adapter is working in Ubuntu under VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox

I have set up 2 network adapters in mu Ubuntu 16.04 VM: Nat and Host-Only, set up /etc/network/interface as follows:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

#allow-hotplug enp0s8
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
    address 192.168.56.110
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.56.1
```

The problem I am facing that only one of the 2 network adapters is working at any time. With the set up above I can connect to my VM, but the there is WAN connection from the VM. I have followed [advice in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1080675/set-virtualbox-network-for-ubuntu-16-04-client), but when I remove the gateway line, internet is working in the VM, but I cannot connect to the VM from my host.

Another (Debian) VM works fine with the same gateway setting.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From Virtual Box settings, which interface do you use for NAT, and which one for Host-Only?

Comment: What is the IP address of your Host?

Comment: Adapter 1 is set to NAT, Adapter2 is set to Host-only. What do you mean by IP address of my host? I am setting it to 192.168.56.110 in the interfaces file above.

Comment: The IP of the Host-only adapter in Windows Network center is 192.168.56.1

Comment: Can you try configuring the host-only to DHCP?

Comment: Ok, did that and run `service netwworking restart` and both are working now! The IP assigned to host-only is 192.168.56.110 (same I had set up with static settings). My concern is though that the IP can change from time to time which had happenned to my Debian machine, hence I had set up the static IP. Do you have any advice here?

Comment: The problem is not with the IP, the issue is with the gateway. The network interface you set up the gateway on will be used as the default connection to the internet, and maybe because you you use DHCP on the NAT connection, it gets default gateway also, so there are two connections with gateway, so VM has to stop one of them. If so, try setting both connections Statically. If this solution works, let me know so I can write it as an answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62788/discussion-between-okneloper-and-haitham-a-el-ghareeb).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839573/static-ip-in-virtualbox-machine-with-ubuntu-16-04). The solution is to use

```
 network 192.168.56.0
```

Instead of

```
 gateway 192.168.56.1
```